# Is there a way to convert pagintation to collection/array/json Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to convert a pagination to a collection/array to get all items like:

```
Users::where(...)->paginate(15); //paginated
```

Output: 15 per page

```
Users::where(..)->get(); //not paginated
```

Output: all Users per page

So i is it possible to do something like that:

```
Users::where(...)->paginate(15)->removePagination();
```

Wanted output: all Users per page

Comment: what are you trying to do ? is it  Users::where(...)->limit(15)->get(); ? or Users::where(...)->limit(15)->get()->toArray() ?

Comment: nothing with limit() , huh?

Comment: The pagination returns a collection

Comment: @elias.xe i didnt understand what you are trying to achieve.better add expected output so it might help some one to answer

Comment: yes, but with a pagination of 15 per site in this scenario

Comment: So you want to return a collection of all items while paginated?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. I am guessing you already have a paginated result but now you want to get the all rows by calling some method on the paginated collection object. If this is the case then no, the query was already run and the result is the collection object with the paginated result. If you want all the records, then you need to build the query again and call the appropriate method to get all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

- either retrieve the complete query result by chaining `->get()`onto your query.
- call `->paginate()` to retrieve a pagination instance, which automatically retrieves the first page, and it automatically links the `example.com?page=1` url param.
- (there are also some other functions that complete the query like `->pluck()` or `->value()` which might not be applicable to you)

As far as I'm aware you cannot revert to the complete collection instance when you have the pagination retrieved (`\Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`), nor does it make sense to do so since the idea is to retrieve as little data as possible such that your application stays fast.

---

Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do; for instance you can retrieve the total count in the paginator using `SomeModel::query()->paginate()->total()`, among other things. You might not need the complete query after all.

Comment: Also all() will return collection. And youre right, it doesnt make sense

Comment: Yep you're right, although `all()` is a shorthand function for `MyModel::query()->get()` so you cant chain it onto an existing query you're building